# wanted to transfer data from child to parent in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting that "props.myfunction is not a function"
This is my parent file to which I want to get data from its childjs file. As you can see I did pass the function inside the component to receive data but I receive the error on the console and I can't see the output.

PARENT:->

```
 const newExpense=()=>
    {
        const saveExpenseHandler=(enteredExpenseData)=>{
            console.log(enteredExpenseData);
        };
        return (
            
            <div className="newExpense"> 
                <ExpenseForm onSaveExpenseData={saveExpenseHandler}/>   
            </div>
        )
        //onSaveExpenseData is used to pass function (saveExpenseHandler) as a property for props and then to recieve dta from child and bring it back to parent.
    };
```

CHILD:->

```
const ExpenseForm = (props) => {
      const expenseData = {
            title: enteredTitle,
            amount: enteredAmount,
            date: new Date(enteredDate)
             };
    props.onSaveExpenseData(expenseData);
}
```

;

```
and i am getting this error on console-

Uncaught TypeError: props.onSaveExpenseData is not a function
```

Comment: On first glance the code looks alright. Please create a codesandbox/jsfiddle containing a reproduction of the issue at hand. Thank you

Comment: where are you calling `props.onSaveExpenseData(expenseData)` ?

Comment: props.onSaveExpenseData(expenseData)  I m just using this in child and then storing this valur in parent function and then i tried to console there.

Comment: Your ExpenseForm does not return any React element. I don't think it counts as a React Component.

Comment: ohh its does its written but its just the error i m facing is in this section only.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
const ExpenseForm = (props) => {
  const expenseData = {
    title: "ABC",
    amount: "OK",
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => props.onSaveExpenseData(expenseData)}>ok</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: this looks okay but will expenseData be accessible outside the function ExpenseForm ?

Comment: yes you `const expenseData = {
    title: "ABC",
    amount: "OK",
  }; ` can be placed outside